# Dynamically create MySql tables in PHP and keep track of them

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have a website where an admin will manage multiple `projects`.

In terms of structure, a `project` is just a table in the database. All projects will share some fields, but will always have other fields that differ from all other projects. this tables will hold information about documents.

My issue is to find the best way to describe this. Because the admin can crate as many projects as he wants, I was thinking to crate a new table for each project he creates. Initially, all tables will have the same fields, but I will allow the admin to create fields for each project table.

Is there a better way of doing this? Or is it better to create a table containing only the specific project fields and then joining it with a main table that has all common fields ?

My solution is to crate a table for each project, something like so:

```
table_project1(id, title, created_on, project1_field1, project1_field2, ...)
table_project2(id, title, created_on, project2_field1, project2_field2, ...)
```

And so on..

In this example, the `id`, `title` and `created_on` fields(in reality there are around 10 shared fields) are the same for all project tables, but then each project table will have their specific fields (the fields will also be created by the admin)

Another problem is that all fields that will be created dynamically by the admin, I have to also be able to search through them, so I need to keep track of these created fields.

What will be the best or better solution to this ?

Thank you

Comment: how about just one `project` table to keep track of all projects

Comment: if you create table for each project, then you could have hundreds of tables,  and so messy db.

Comment: @AhmedSunny So what will a solution be though? I cannot create a single table with all the fields for each project, that will get big in no time and will have hundreds of columns.

Comment: what i did is, I made a temp table, with params, and a temp data table, that contains data. the tamp param table contains 10 char,10 int, 10 date etc fields, and you can define a new project with specific fields you required, and the data for those fields save in temp data table in the relevent fields

Comment: @popeye Can you elaborate more on this? I don't understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: there are several things you need to ask yourself, for example, can these extra fields be added multiple times after the project creation, or is it locked after created? If the first, maybe you can inspire yourself from wordpress options, where options are referenced in the main table, and another table holds the records. Also, will this hold a lot of data, and do you want to prevent joins for the sake of efficiency, or is it not that important?

Comment: This does indeed sound like a bad idea. You want to solve the problem that an admin can add fields. Such a field has probably three properties: a name, a value and it is part of a project. There you go, you've got a table to store extra fields, with three columns. If you add an extra table to keep track of which fields an admin has added your work is done.

Comment: @Kaddath After creating a project, then the admin can create as many (unique) fields as he needs for each project. Theoretically he only structures the table once and that is it, but nothing will forbid him to add other fields later on. As for how many records, no more than 10.000 per table.

Comment: `table Projects - id, project_id (foreign key to table Project)` AND `table Project - id, project1_field1, project1_field2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, I would go with three tables:

1: You main project table with the fields that are always present:

```
projects_table (id, title, created_on, project1_field1, project1_field2, ...)
```

2: A second table to keep track of extra added fields by the admins:

```
fields_table (id, projectId, name)
```

3: A third table to keep track of values of added fields:

```
values_table (id, projectId, fieldId, value)
```

Note that `projectId` in the third table is not really necessary, since it is already present in the second table. Whether or not to add superfluous fields like this depends on what you want to do with the data, and any efficiency concerns you might have.

You can add columns to the tables as needed, like `created_on`. Can you see how this would work?

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense. Would it make sense to merge the second and third table? Like adding a column "value"? Is that the same thing in the end?

Comment: The second and third table serve two different functions. The second one is to keep track of fields that were added by the admin, regardless of any values that a field might get. The third table is specifically there for the values. You cannot merge them and keep both functionalities in a clean way. Anyway, going from unknown many tables to just three is progress, I would think. :-)

Comment: Oh yes, I see now. So I think this is it, everything should the tight up with just the three tables. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, just a follow up question if you don't mind. How would you manage the type of the field and the value? For example, I will make the admin choose what type the field will be. There will be only 3 types allows, VARCHAR, INT and BOOLEAN. I added a "type" column in the fields_table, but how would i reflect this type on the values_table for the "value" field? Is it even possible, or I have to make the "value" column VARCHAR always? Thank you

Comment: There are several solutions possible, of which you suggested one. That's not a bad idea at all. Alternatively you could have different tables for different types of fields. It all depends on which types you need and how you're going to process the data. Storing an INT or BOOLEAN in a VARCHAR is slightly less efficient computationally, you also waste a bit of file space, and you cannot add a type like BLOB or even long texts. However, using separate tables can make your queries more complex. So it all depends.

Comment: The third table can be improved with the tips [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) .  Even better is to serialize them into a JSON string and to put in `projects` table.

Comment: @RickJames Serializing the dynamical columns as a JSON string would make them harder to reach for queries, you would have to use MySQL JSON functions, and it goes against any concept of [data normalization](https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/sql-design-why-you-need-database-normalization).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - The fields will be almost as hard to get at in the `EAV` schema that Table 3 implies.  Conclusion:  Put columns you need to search/sort on in _columns_; don't bury them in JSON or key-value EAV.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have shared fields between Projects, I'll suggest you to have them in one table
like follows:

```
Projects (id, title, created_on, ..., additional_fields_table_name)
```

Note that I added a custom shared field named `additional_fields_table_name`, this field will store the name of the table that will contain the name of the table where you can find the fields related to this project.

For example:
you created a project named `Dev-1`, then created additional fields for it, it will be stored in something like `Dev_1_additional_fields`, they will be linked using `id` as primary/foreign key.

I guess you might find it useful.

Comment: So basically create a table for each project that will hold project specific fields and then joining it with the main table, right?

Comment: exactly, it will help you a lot